# Why does the following code shows the last month in the array instead of showing the months with the highest and the lowest rainfall?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment where I need to get user input for the amount of rainfall for each month. At the end I need to average the rainfall as well as display the month (using the name of the month) that had the highest and the lowest rainfall. Everything works with the exception of displaying the lowest and highest month. For some reason my code always displays December instead of the actual lowest and highest month. The lowestMonth = MONTHS[count]; and highestMonth = MONTHS[countup]; are the lines of code that I suspect are causing some problems. Appreciate any help the community can offer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 12;
    double RAINFALL[SIZE];
    string MONTHS[SIZE] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

    for (int counter = 0; counter < SIZE; counter++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter rainfall for " << MONTHS[counter] << ": ";
        cin >> RAINFALL[counter];

        while (RAINFALL[counter] < 0.00) // Input validation to prevent neg amounts being entered
        {
            cout << "Invalid Data (negative rainfall)!" << endl;
            cout << "Please re-enter rainfall for " << MONTHS[counter] << ": ";
            cin >> RAINFALL[counter];
        }
    }

    int tnum;
    double average, sum = 0;
    for (tnum = 0; tnum < SIZE; tnum++)
        sum += RAINFALL[tnum];
    average = sum / SIZE;
    cout << "Average rainfall = " << average << endl;

    int count;
    int lowest;
    string lowestMonth = MONTHS[0];
    lowest = RAINFALL[0];
    for (count = 1; count < SIZE; count++)
    {
        if (RAINFALL[count] < lowest)
            lowest = RAINFALL[count]; 
        lowestMonth = MONTHS[count];
    }

    cout << "Lowest rainfall in " << lowestMonth << " of: " << lowest << endl;

    int countup;
    int highest;
    string highestMonth = MONTHS[0];
    highest = RAINFALL[0];
    for (countup = 1; countup < SIZE; countup++)
    {
        if (RAINFALL[countup] > highest)
            highest = RAINFALL[countup];
            highestMonth = MONTHS[countup];
    }

    cout << "Highest rainfall in " << highestMonth << " of: " << highest << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `lowest` or `highest` before you use them so the behavior is undefined. You could also combine the lowest and highest in a single loop (or even calculate it as you do the data entry)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a bracket in your if-statement, so only the first line is executed.

```
for (count = 1; count < SIZE; count++)
{
    if (RAINFALL[count] < lowest) { // <-- BRACKET
        lowest = RAINFALL[count]; 
        lowestMonth = MONTHS[count];
    } // <-- BRACKET
}
```

There are more modular ways of doing this, of course:

```
std::string lowest_month = MONTHS[
    std::min_element(&RAINFALL[0], &RAINFALL[SIZE]) - &RAINFALL[0]
];
```

Comment: OMG, kinda embarrassed. New to coding. Kosta, awesome, thanks for your help